# Execute command line equivalent to Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); in JNI C

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I was developing an app which had requirement to implement root detection logic, so by researching I found some detection logic in JAVA and had implemented following class.

```
class RootDetection {

    public boolean isDeviceRooted() {

        return checkForBinary("su") || checkForBinary("busybox") || checkForMaliciousPaths() || checkSUonPath()
                || detectRootManagementApps() || detectPotentiallyDangerousApps() || detectRootCloakingApps()
                || checkForDangerousProps() || checkForRWPaths()
                || detectTestKeys() || checkSuExists();
    }

    private boolean detectTestKeys() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        String buildFinger = Build.FINGERPRINT;
        String product = Build.PRODUCT;
        String hardware = Build.HARDWARE;
        String display = Build.DISPLAY;
        System.out.println("Java: build: " + buildTags + "\nFingerprint: " + buildFinger + "\n Product: " + product + "\n Hardware: " + hardware + "\nDisplay: " + display);
        return (buildTags != null) && (buildTags.contains("test-keys") || buildFinger.contains("genric.*test-keys") || product.contains("generic") || product.contains("sdk") || hardware.contains("goldfish") || display.contains(".*test-keys"));
    }


    private boolean detectRootManagementApps() {
        return detectRootManagementApps(null);
    }


    private boolean detectRootManagementApps(String[] additionalRootManagementApps) {


        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(knownRootAppsPackages));
        if (additionalRootManagementApps != null && additionalRootManagementApps.length > 0) {
            packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalRootManagementApps));
        }

        return isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(packages);
    }


    private boolean detectPotentiallyDangerousApps() {
        return detectPotentiallyDangerousApps(null);
    }

    private boolean detectPotentiallyDangerousApps(String[] additionalDangerousApps) {


        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(knownDangerousAppsPackages));
        if (additionalDangerousApps != null && additionalDangerousApps.length > 0) {
            packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalDangerousApps));
        }

        return isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(packages);
    }


    private boolean detectRootCloakingApps() {
        return detectRootCloakingApps(null);
    }


    private boolean detectRootCloakingApps(String[] additionalRootCloakingApps) {


        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(knownRootCloakingPackages));
        if (additionalRootCloakingApps != null && additionalRootCloakingApps.length > 0) {
            packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalRootCloakingApps));
        }

        return isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(packages);
    }

    private boolean checkForBinary(String filename) {

        for (String path : suPaths) {
            String completePath = path + filename;
            File f = new File(completePath);
            boolean fileExists = f.exists();
            if (fileExists) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkForMaliciousPaths() {
        for (String path : maliciousPaths) {
            File f = new File(path);
            boolean fileExists = f.exists();
            if (fileExists) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkSUonPath() {
        for (String pathDir : System.getenv("PATH").split(":")) {
            if (new File(pathDir, "su").exists()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String[] propsReader() {
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        try {
            inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop").getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String propval = "";
        try {
            propval = new Scanner(inputstream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

        }

        return propval.split("\n");
    }

    private String[] mountReader() {
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        try {
            inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount").getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (inputstream == null) return null;

        String propval = "";
        try {
            propval = new Scanner(inputstream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return propval.split("\n");
    }

    private boolean isAnyPackageFromListInstalled(List<String> packages) {

        PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();

        for (String packageName : packages) {
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                return true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkForDangerousProps() {

        final Map<String, String> dangerousProps = new HashMap<>();
        dangerousProps.put("ro.debuggable", "1");
        dangerousProps.put("ro.secure", "0");

        String[] lines = propsReader();
        for (String line : lines) {
            for (String key : dangerousProps.keySet()) {
                if (line.contains(key)) {
                    String badValue = dangerousProps.get(key);
                    badValue = "[" + badValue + "]";
                    if (line.contains(badValue)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkForRWPaths() {

        String[] lines = mountReader();
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] args = line.split(" ");

            if (args.length < 4) {
                continue;
            }

            String mountPoint = args[1];
            String mountOptions = args[3];

            for (String pathToCheck : pathsThatShouldNotBeWrtiable) {
                if (mountPoint.equalsIgnoreCase(pathToCheck)) {
                    for (String option : mountOptions.split(",")) {

                        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("rw")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkSuExists() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"which", "su"});
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            return in.readLine() != null;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }

}
```

but now to increase security I want to do this root detection logic in native C++ JNI code. I managed to migrate package detection code to JNI C but am not able to find anything regarding these 3 functions

checkForDangerousProps(),checkForRWPaths(),checkSuExists()

these 3 use Runtime.getRuntime().exec which am not able to find. can someone help me in converting this 3 logics to JNI C one from above code? Help would be really appreciated.

Pls guys help.

Comment: I think the methods you're referring to are from RootBeer or one of its derivatives. Presumably you could look at the source code for RootBeer to find out how these methods are implemented. Mostly they're just using `Runtime.exec()` to run various Linux commands. I guess you could do the same thing in C using `popen()` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kevin. I had searched it on stack overflow and surprisingly code looks similar but have minor changes. so as you mentioned about Rootbeer I had a look now and it has only path detection logic in the JNI C. nothing related to above 3 logics in JNI.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do any of this in JNI, if it can be done in Java. Introducing JNI into an Android project creates a heap of additional complexity.

Comment: Our security expert suggested it since reverse engineering code from JNI is difficult.

Comment: But if you base your root-detection logic on something that is already well-known in Java, nobody would need to reverse-engineer your JNI implementation -- they'd just look at the existing Java, right? If you want a method of root detection that is hard to defeat, you should implement it entirely yourself, using techniques that are not already well known.